# Update in coredata happening improperly

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm updating a certain value in coredata like so...

```
 let managedContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
 let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ProductFields> = ProductFields.fetchRequest()

 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sellerId = %@", self.mySellerId) //CRASH HERE


 do {

   let array_categories = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
   let cat = array_categories[0]

   cat.setValue("1", forKey: "isSync")

   try managedContext.save()
   } catch let error as NSError {
          print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }
```

But it crashes at the line `fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sellerId = %@", self.mySellerId)` It doesn't give any specific reason for crash..just `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS...`

But a kinda strange thing happens. I dragged a label onto my screen, give it a name as `sellerIdLabel` or so..and then assigned the value of the `sellerID` to it. Now I modified the line where the crash occured as

`fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sellerId = %@", self.theSellerIDLabel.text!)`

i.e I replaced `self.mySellerId` with `self.theSellerIDLabel.text!`. Now the crash is resolved and everything worked perfect. I'm confused about this seemingly strange behavior. Why is this happening..why it didn't work in the first case..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of crash often happens when you try to build a predicate using incorrect types.

Check the type of your sellerId. If it's not a string, then you shouldn't use %@.

For example, if it's an integer then this line:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sellerId = %@", self.mySellerId)
```

should be:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "sellerId = %d", self.mySellerId)
```

Comment: Thanks @Taarna. It worked. But are there other types also apart from `%@` & `%d` where we should be careful..?